# Android JDOM2 xml parsing, IOExcetion

Tags: java, android, xml, eclipse, jdom-2

I am trying to parse xml from URL with jdom-2.0.6.jar, but i get IOException:

`IOException: Couldn't open "here is xml link"`

That what I am doing:

```
import org.jdom2.Document;
import org.jdom2.Element;
import org.jdom2.JDOMException;
import org.jdom2.input.SAXBuilder;

String myurl = "https://myfile.xml";

  SAXBuilder builder = new SAXBuilder();

  try {
        Document document =  builder.build(myurl);
        Element rootNode = document.getRootElement().getChild("myroot");
      } catch (IOException io) {
        Log.d("IOException", io.getMessage());
    } catch (JDOMException jdomex) {
        Log.d("JDOMException", jdomex.getMessage());
    }
```

The same code works well in Eclipse, but not in Android Studio. So what is wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did not have in log (android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException) exception, but after using this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6343299/6151277) I finally parsed xml.

Answer (score 0):

Change to Log.w("IOException", io.getMessage(), io) to get the full stack trace, maybe we can identify the problem from there.

Comment: It prints the same, no more info.